# Get index value of nested list item with jQuery

Tags: jquery, nested

I'm trying to get the index value of an nested `li` item once I click on the item itself.

As you can see on the console I could get the index values of the items that are not nested properly but the nested ones are giving me 0 or 1 instead of 2 or 3, naturally.

Is there a way I could find the index value of the `li` even though its inside another div within the `ul`?

```js
 $('li a').on('click', function() {
   console.log($($(this)["0"].offsetParent).find('li') );
   console.log($(this).parent().index() )
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 0</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <div class="group">
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </div>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$(this).index('a')` the `.index()` could have selector param. http://devdocs.io/jquery/index/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `index()` property in a wrong way, try this code.

```js
$('li a').on('click', function() {
  console.log( $(this).index("a") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 0</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <div class="group">
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </div>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```